# Preg_replace special characters &

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, special-characters

Good afternoon,

I have an error in my preg_replace. I would like to replace `&&` with only one `&`, and `?&` with `?`.

My code looks like this:

```
$reg = preg_replace("#\&\&#is", "&
        ", $reg);    
$reg = preg_replace("#\?\&#is", "?
        ", $reg);
```

Could you please help me fix this? I am sure, it some basic error, so sorry for that...

Thanks!

Comment: Why the newlines in the replacement string? Are you sure it's `&` that gets sent, and it's not `&amp;`?

Comment: @knittl I am sure it's "&". Well, it shouldn't be newlines, I just don't know, how to make this work...

Comment: Do you want to replace just 2 `&`s or all `&`s >=2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to escape `&` only the `?`

```
$reg = preg_replace("#&&#", "&", $reg);

$reg = preg_replace("#\?&#", "?", $reg);
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me...
original `$reg` contains "?(space)&" so I've tried `$reg = preg_replace("#\? &#", "?", $reg);` but when I try to `echo "$reg";` nothing changed..

Comment: @HSturma then you need to add the space to the regex... ``$reg = preg_replace("#\?\s&#", "?", $reg);`` `\s` is for whitespace

Comment: and still nothing.. I have really no idea, why it doesn't work...
Here is exactly what the original reg contains: " ? &lang=en"

Comment: @HSturma are you viewing the input/output of `$reg` in a browser? If so view the source, not the rendered page. You might have multiple spaces.

Comment: @chris85 how can I see the not rendered output?

Comment: @HSturma View the source, not the browser output.

Comment: oh, ok, i've replaces spaces with a letter and there are 2 spaces. it works now :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the two regexs into one.

```
echo preg_replace("#([?&])\s*&#", "$1", ' ? &lang=en');
```

Output:

```
 ?lang=en
```

Your modifiers didn't make sense since you aren't using alpha characters or the `.`.

Also `&` isn't a special regex character, just `?`. If in a character class (`[]`) neither will need to be replaced.

Regex101 Demo: https://regex101.com/r/iS4mQ0/1